# Prove that for all square matrices A and positive intgers n that $(A^n)T=(AT)^n$?

Tags: matrices

I need to prove the following:

> For all square matrices $A$ and positive integers $n$, $(A^n)^T=(A^T)^n$.

$A^T$ stands for transpose of the matrix $A$.

I would really appreciate it if you prove this one.

Comment: Hint: think about spectral decomposition

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that:
$$(AB)^T = B^T A^T$$
You can use induction and the fact that:
$$A^n=A^{n-1}A$$

Answer (score 1):

You can consider $A$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ ( with respect to the standard basis). Then $\langle (A^n)^Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, (A^n)y \rangle = \langle A^Tx, (A^{n-1})y  \rangle=  \langle (A^T)^2x, (A^{n-2})y \rangle = \ldots =  \langle (A^T)^nx, y \rangle$ for all $x, y$. Thus $(A^T)^n = (A^n)^T$.